# Vimscript or macro to "rotate" column 20 (or n) vertically?

Tags: vimscript, macro, register

Given an integer `n` and a block of text, rotate every character or element in the *n*-th column up or down to the next position that exists.

```
A line with more than k characters.
A longer line with more than k character.
A short line.
Rotate here: ------v--
This is long enough.

This is not enough.
Wrapping around to the first line.
```

Output:

```
A line with more thtn k characters.
A longer line with aore than k character.
A short line.
Rotate here: ------m--
This is long enoughv

This is not enough.
Wrapping around to .he first line.
```

Rotating the *k*-th column of the same input where 35 < *k* < 42 would yield the input text unchanged.

Related: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/182363/rotate-a-column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
" s : start line, e : end line, c : col
function! RotateColumn(s, e, c)
  " place cursor at line a:s
  call cursor(a:s, 1)
  " search backward to find last line that's longer enough
  if search(printf('\v%%>%dl%%<%dl%%%dc', a:s-1, a:e+1, a:c), 'b')
    " copy current character into @"
    norm! yl
    " for each line, if character exists in screen column a:c, swap it with @"
    exec printf('%d,%dg/\v%%%dc/ norm! %d|vp', a:s, a:e, a:c, a:c)
  endif
endfunction
```

**update**

No longer need to find last line.

```
" s : start line, e : end line, c : col
function! RotateColumn2(s, e, c)
  " set @" to any letter
  let @"='x'
  " copy all lines to below a:e
  exec a:s.','.a:e.'t'.a:e
  " for each line, if character exists in screen column a:c, swap it with @"
  exec printf('%d,%dg/\v%%%dc/ norm! %d|vp', a:s, a:e*2-a:s+1, a:c, a:c)
  " remove original lines
  exec a:s.','.a:e.'d'
endfunction
```